# Passing multiple parametes in Where-In SQL- Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle11g, where-in

I am trying to write a query passing three variables together:-

```
select 
a,b,c,*
from table1 where
(a,b,c) in (('1','2','3'),('4','5','6'));
```

This gives me results when none of the values are null.

However when I try to pass atleast one of them as null/blank it gives me invalid relational operator error:-

```
select 
a,b,c,*
from table1 where
(a,b,c) in (('1','2',null),('4','5',''));
```

```
  [Error Code: 920, SQL State: 42000]  ORA-00920: invalid relational operator
```

Could you please help me with a workaround to handle this?
I can use union of three different queries but that is error prone with huge data to query.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you giving it options to only pull non-null values, try something like this

```
select 
a,b,c,*
from table1 where
(a in ('1', '4')) or (b in ('2','5')) or (c in ('3','6'));
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer.However this is not giving me desired results.It is replacing the null/blank with other values in the in clause.

Comment: On the contrary, this query seems to do exactly what you wanted. *Where* and *what* is replacing null/blank? Your second query would just be `... or c is null`